# Deploying configurable application template for ArcGIS Online or Portal for ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-portal, arcgis-online-webmap

I am trying to use a configurable application template, Interactive Filter ([Live Example Here](https://www.arcgis.com/apps/InteractiveFilter/index.html)) to create an online map in ArcGIS Online to be shared with others. I want my users to be able to filter the different layers that I have on my map. Those layers are uploaded as hosted layers under "Contents" in my ArcGIS Online account.

The Interactive Filter configurable application template is on [GitHub](https://github.com/Esri/InteractiveFilter) and I have download and un-zipped it.

I really don't understand where to begin because I am very new to interactive and online maps. As far as I understand from the "Readme" file, I have to configure the JavaScript files and HTML and then upload the app in my ArcGIS Online account and share the URL of the app to the end users.

I want my map to be Sweden not USA, and I have multiple layers on the Sweden polygon that I want to use the filter on.

Where do I start?

Comment: Have you downloaded Web AppBuilder for ArcGIS Developer Edition?  https://community.esri.com/thread/205211-publishing-custom-widget-in-arcgis-online

Comment: @ZacharyOrdo-GISP Yes thank you for pointing me at the right direction! I have downloaded Web AppBuilder for ArcGIS Developer Edition now and setup it up. But I can't seem to upload my Web App template... I have downloaded the Template and it's a .zip file when I try to import it via Web AppBuilder it's says : "Error Parsing Server result:"

Comment: I may have pointed you in the wrong direction.  I incorrectly assumed this was a custom widget.  However, upon further review, this is for deploying a configurable application template, which has completely different steps to deploy.  Do you have a web server?  It appears you must have your own web server available to deploy a configurable application template.  I do not believe you can deploy it directly on ArcGIS Online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to deploy this configurable application template, you will need to host it from your web server.  A configurable application template cannot be hosted on ArcGIS Online, nor can it be uploaded via Portal for ArcGIS.

If you have a website you already host internally, this should be as simple as hopping onto the machine that hosts your web server, opening Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager (or a similar application), navigating to your site, right-clicking on your site, going to "Add Application...", and pointing the application to wherever you've placed the Interactive Filter application (such as C:\InteractiveFilter).  In this case, the URL for accessing your application could look something like http://www.mysite.com/InteractiveFilter

[image: Create a new application on your locally hosted website]

Otherwise, if you're using a web hosting service such as GoDaddy or HostGator, you'll need to upload your template to your host.